# Adding an Icon to My Edit Form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to add an icon to my edit form. The Icon appears as expected but it does not react to click event.

Using free jqGrid 4.13

In the `colModel`:

```
{name:'characteristic', index:'characteristic', width:150, editable: true,
    editoptions:{rows:'3',cols:'50'}, editrules:{edithidden:true},
    formoptions:{rowpos:3, colpos:1,label:"Characteristic:",
    elmsuffix: " <img class='genericnotes' src='/QMSWebApp/Images/addnote[3].jpg'>"},
    edittype:'textarea'},
```

In the loadComplete:

```
$('.genericnotes').on("click", function(){
    var tControl = this.name;
    alert(tControl);

    //$('.miscdisplay').load("/QMSWebApp/FirstArticleControllerServlet",
    //{lifecycle:"faieditlistdisplay",
    //tControl:tControl,
    //source:0});
    //$('.miscdisplay').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong to use `$('.genericnotes').on("click", function(){...});` inside of `loadComplete` because the edit form is not exist at the moment. You should use for example `beforeShowForm` callback of form editing instead. Free jqGrid allows to specify form editing options/callbacks inside of `formEditing` option of jqGrid (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods)). Thus you can bind `click` handle to the `img.genericnotes` by usage of

```
formEditing: {
    beforeShowForm: function () {
        $("#characteristic") // select textarea#characteristic
            .next(".genericnotes")
            .on("click", function () {
                alert("Click");
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var tControl = $(this).attr("name");`

Comment: That did not work but I don't think that is the source of the problem. It acts like the click event is not being bound to the icon in the loadComplete method.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Okidok, will try :)